# raw and smart pointers mixed function overloading

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, smart-pointers

In my project I have smart and raw pointers mixed. Some functions need to work for both, the raw and the smart ones, in the functions i only use the `->`, `=` and `*` on the pointers. My Question is if I have to write every function twice or even more times if I have multiple arguments, or if there is something I can do so i could pass both, smart and raw pointers. I was thinking about a wrapper class arroud the pointers or something like this.

Comment: When you `=` what type do you assign-from (and/or to)?  Same type always?  Ownership is tricky, no idea how to do *that* generically.  Everything else, use templates and/or type erasure.

Answer (score 0):

(This question would benefit a lot from a code example, however I will attempt to answer.)

What I would recommend is to pass by *reference* or *const reference*, and then use `*` operator on either kind of pointer when you pass the argument to the function.

Since your functions should work with raw or smart, and it's not obvious to you that this is impossible :D, it means to me that the implementations shouldn't need to do anything with ownership. Like, take a copy of the `shared_ptr` for some reason. This means, they are better written to take references, since they don't care about the ownership.